# cover modal view with a view before it loads

Tags: iphone, ios, modalviewcontroller

For example I have a ViewController named firstViewController. Then I would like to call another ViewController named myModalViewController.

```
[self presentModalViewController:myModalViewController animated:YES];
```

But, I like to display a view with an activity indicator as it presents the modal view and after it loads the modal view lets say after 3secs.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the viewDidAppear of myModalViewController add an activity indicator ... start timer for 3 seconds and start a timer for 3 seconds .. once it is done hide the activity indicator.. as simple as that.